# Accessing element of complex Mat in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, std, mat

I need to access the real part specific element of a `cv::Mat` that contains `std::complex<double>`'s.

OpenCV provides codes of how to create a complex `cv::Mat_` [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) (search the page for the keyword "complex" and the first mention of that word is where the example is).

Here is my attempt:

```
Mat B = Mat_<std::complex<double> >(3, 3);
cout << B.depth() << ", " << B.channels() << endl;
B.at<double>(0, 0) = 0;
cout << "B(0,0) = " << B.at<double>(0, 0).real(); // Error due to .rea()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mat` is filled with the type `std::complex<double>` but you're requesting a `double` when you write `B.at<double>(0, 0)`; the return type is `double`, which doesn't have a `.real()` method. Instead you need to return the complex type which your `Mat` holds:

```
cout << "B(0,0) = " << B.at<std::complex<double> >(0, 0).real();
```

> B(0,0) = 0

If you want to set an imaginary number, you'll need to actually pass that into the matrix, otherwise it just sets the real part:

```
B.at<double>(0, 0) = 2;
cout << "B(0,0) = " << B.at<std::complex<double> >(0, 0);
```

> B(0,0) = (2,0)

```
B.at<std::complex<double> >(0, 0) = std::complex<double> (2, 1);
cout << "B(0,0) = " << B.at<std::complex<double> >(0, 0);
```

> B(0,0) = (2,1)

Comment: Wow Alexander, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you friend!